# htaccess add query to the end of the link

Tags: .htaccess

I need to know how to redirect 
http://test.com/test.php to http://test.com/test.php?var=foo

& also if it's http://test.com/test.php?var=foo to be http://test.com/test.php?var=foo&var2=foo

If this will cause a loop just tell me how to achieve it and I am going to test

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try, or are you simply asking for code?

Comment: It is possible to do the first example, however the second example you might need to use a different approach so it will not enter a loop and if you have more than 2 multilevel that needs to be rewritten then this is not an option for as long as you send it to itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^([^.]+\.php)$ /$1?var=foo [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)var=foo(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^([^.]+\.php)$ /$1?var2=foo [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I',m sorry forgot to mention in the question that I don't need this for a specific file need to do this with any php file
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply
in the 5th line the vas=foo isn't something that will always be the same it differs :)

Can you guide me to htaccess explaination so I can try to find out edits myself.

Comment: You are changing a not-se-well-defined question many times. You can see docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html